# Multiple premoves

Tags: online-chess

I often enjoy being able to play (online) chess with premoves activated. However, I wondered from the beginning why multiple premoves at once weren't allowed. Example: where my opponent's queen is next to his king and I premove to take his queen (provided he does not move his own queen first) then why can't I additionally guess that he will take back with his king and also premove **his** king to take my queen? As long as my opponent is still thinking, I should be allowed to premove as many moves as I want – at least I think this would be a nice variant.

Comment: On chess.com you're allowed to do this.

Comment: Another option would be to make an alternate premove in case your first choice premove is illegal. I wonder if this is allowed anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Pre-moving is not a chess variant; it's a *feature* of several online chess sites. You can't pre-move in over-the-board games.

It's up to the owners of those chess sites to decide where their development budget goes to. If you know what your opponent is going to do, they probably know it too and can quickly make their next move, before you have the chance to make multiple pre-moves. Situations where you would actually benefit from being able to make multiple pre-moves are probably rare enough that they do not want to spend time/energy/money on such a feature.

Comment: Really? It's a situation that happens in my blitz games all the time (where I know to 95% certainty where my opponent will move). I don't think it would be to costly to implement, either. Whether it's technically a variant or not is of course subjective- I had just read the question where some were describing "being allowed to use using arrows" when playing as a "variant" so I guess I was biased in using the term.

Comment: If you know what your opponent is going to do, they probably know it too and can quickly make their next move, before you have the chance to make multiple pre-moves.

Comment: Good point and probably true in many cases.

Answer (score 3):

> Example: where my opponent's queen is next to his king and I premove
>   to take his queen (provided he does not move his own queen first) then
>   why can't I additionally guess that he will take back with his king
>   and also premove his king to take my queen?

You can only premove your own moves. You can guess that he will take back with his king but not make the move for him.

One variant of chess where you can do the equivalent of multiple premoves and where it is common is correspondence chess.

It is common to not just send one move as a reply to your opponent but a number of different sequences of several moves from which your opponent can choose or can play something completely different. This has the same effect as premoving in online chess of speeding up the game and gaining time on the clock albeit for both players.

Comment: Thanks for reply- I forgot you can do something very similar in correspondence chess. I would still like to try it out in online chess (maybe as a secret weapon against clock tickers, haha), should it be made possible at some point.

Answer (score 3):

> I should be allowed to premove as many moves as I want

Wherever you play, it is their site, and their rules, so they get to decide what to implement. I agree with Glorfindel that it is relatively rare that most players would want to take the chance on multiple premoves as you do, so why bother programming it?

If this is important to you, then I suggest sending the site a suggestion. They might implement it.

Comment: Of course the site owners make their own rules. You "summarized" my sentence making it sound like I'm demanding something- leaving off the last part: "at least I think this would be nice" which makes clear this is just an idea and not a demand. Sure, I can request it directly- we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Many sites allow you to do multiple premoves. The site is free to allow a single premove, multiple ones, or ban them completely

Comment: I think it'd be better to mention 1 or 2 sites as an example because most of the sites that I know only allow 1 premove.

Comment: Lichess allows this, at least in correspondence games.

Comment: chess.com allows multiple premoves in blitz. chess24 only allows one as far as I know

Comment: Examples: freechess.org allows multiple pre-moves, lichess.org allows only one